# COM visible List from C# to vb6

Tags: c#, generics, vb6, com-interop

I have ClassLibrary (in visual studio 2010 C#) with a class Car:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ClassLibrary1.Car")]
public class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        Name = "";
        Parts = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

But when I use it in vb6 project: there is no property "Parts":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMfEi.jpg

What can I do to make property **List<>** visible?

Of course, the file "AssemblyInfo.cs" contains:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

P.S. I really do not want to create for each List the class, like this:

```
public class Parts
{
    private List<string> _parts;

    public Parts()
    {
        _parts = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(string part)
    {
        _parts.Add(part);
    }

    public string GetAt(int index)
    {
        if (0 <= index && index < _parts.Count)
            return _parts[index];
        return "";
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _parts.Clear();
    }

    public int Count{ get{ return _parts.Count; } }
}
```

because there are too many.

Answer (score 3):

COM does not support generic collections; you'll have to use an array or `ArrayList` instead:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ClassLibrary1.Car")]
public class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        Name = "";
        Parts = new string[];
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] Parts { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use a List behind-the-scenes you could use a `List<string>` as a backing variable, then change the property accessors to translate the list to/from an array:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ClassLibrary1.Car")]
public class Car
{

    private List<string> _Parts;

    public Car()
    {
        Name = "";
        _Parts = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] Parts 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _Parts.ToArray();
        } 
        set
        {
            _Parts = new List<string>(value);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, if you just inherit from the generic to make a concrete definition (ie `class Parts : List<Part>`) and add the attributes, would that be acceptable for Com Visibility?

Comment: I added class:
   `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("Modem_TAO_Well3DView.Parts")]
    public class Parts : List<string>
    {
        public Parts()
        {
            MaxCount = 50;
        }

        public static int MAX_COUNT = 50;

        public int GetMaxCount()
        {
            return 50;
        }

        public int MaxCount { get; set; }
    }`
But nothing is visible (properties, fields, etc). Perhaps you meant IList<Part>

Comment: I hope - there is a class attribute that allows access to the property List

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to do so, but had:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ClassLibrary1.Car")]
public class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        Name = "";
        Parts = new Parts();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parts Parts { get; set; }
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ClassLibrary1.Parts")]
public class Parts : IList<string>
{
    private List<string> _parts;

    public Parts()
    {
        _parts = new List<string>();
    }

    #region IList<string> Members

    public int IndexOf(string item)
    {
        return _parts.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, string item)
    {
        _parts.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _parts.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _parts[index];
        }
        set
        {
            _parts[index] = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<string> Members

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        _parts.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _parts.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(string item)
    {
        return _parts.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(string[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _parts.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _parts.Count; }
    }

    public bool Remove(string item)
    {
        return _parts.Remove(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<string> Members


    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<string> Members

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In vb6:

```
Option Explicit
Dim car As New ClassLibrary1.car
Dim parts As New ClassLibrary1.parts

Private Sub Form_Load()

    parts.Add "wheel"
    parts.Add "door"
    parts.Add "hood"
    parts.Add "trunk"

    car.Name = "GAS-24"
    Set car.parts = parts
    car.parts.RemoveAt (0)
End Sub
```

Drawback of this approach is a lot of code:(

Let me know, if anyone knows something like this:

```
//**[MakeVisibleListInVB6]**
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ClassLibrary1.Car")]
public class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        Name = "";
        Parts = new Parts();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Parts { get; set; }
}
```